# Python requests post not sending string

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

So I'm trying to POST a simple stuff onto my page using Python.

```
r = requests.Session().post(
    'http://mypage.com/add?token=%s&title=%s&opt=&opt=true&token=%s' % (token, title, token),
    headers = headers,
    proxies = proxy,
    timeout = max_timeout,
    )
```

The problem is: if `title` is, for example `Hello World!` it works perfectly, but if `title` is `Hello World! Visit www.google.com`it won't work.

What I've found so far is that `title` string wont send if it contains punctuations, in this case `www.google.com` has two `.` so it wont post...

Is this normal in Python? I've also tried to use `urllib.quote` `urllib.urlencode` and more, but same result...

In addition, if you ask why I don't use `data = mydata` inside `post()`object is because, if you have noticed, I'm using the param `token` and `opt` twice, so if I make a `data` object like this:

```
data = {
    "token": token,
    "title": "title",
    "opt": "",
    "opt": 'value',
    "token": token
}
```

Obviously it wont work as it has duplicated `key` values.

Comment: You are POSTing an empty body however, you are only using query parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are POST-ing an empty body, and only using query parameters. `requests` can send duplicate keys just fine, both in request parameters and in a POST body. All you have to do is use a sequence of key-value tuples instead of a dictionary:

```
params = [
    ("token", token),
    ("title", "title"),
    ("opt", ""),
    ("opt", 'value'),
    ("token": token),
]
```

These will be encoded for you when used as query parameters or as application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST body.

To send these as a POST body, use the `data` keyword argument:

```
requests.post('http://mypage.com/add', data=params,
              headers = headers, proxies = proxy, timeout = max_timeout)
```

or use `params` to send these as query parameters (in the URL):

```
requests.post('http://mypage.com/add', params=params,
              headers = headers, proxies = proxy, timeout = max_timeout)
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn Pieters I will test as soon as I get home, but it seems you know what you're talking about so I think it'll work :)